# create transaction data set R

Tags: r, transactions, dataset

I am trying to extract all frequent data set using eclat algorithm.
My data are stored in a vector of lists like this

> ```
> [[1]] 
> [1] "item 1"               "item 3" 
> [3] "item 4"               "item 4"
> ```

```
>  [[2]] 
[1] "item 12"               "item 23"
[3] "item 41"               "item 41 
[5] "item 12"               "item 23" 
[7] "item 41"               "item 41
```

I would like to create a transaction data set like this

> [[1]]

```
[1] "item 1" 


[[2]]  

[1] "item 3" 

[[3]] 


[3] "item 4" 


[[4]] 


[4]

 "item 4"
```

Any idea to do this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your output, you want to convert a list of vectors to a longer list of length-1 vectors.
If this is the case, you can try:

```
as.list(unlist(yourList))
```

Comment: Sorry, last question. Is it possible to make it in form of table : id1 list item 1 .. item N     id2 item1 ... item 2  ? thanks

Comment: I think you need to explain this in more detail; it's probably best to create a new question

Comment: Yes sure I will create another question . Thank you

Comment: I make a new question , thank you      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778230/create-array-data-set-r